# Connect with https (SSL) in my iOS App

Tags: ios, ssl, https, certificate

I want connect my app to my database with https . 
But I don know what i have to do ?
I have files with jks format, crt format .
I want to know what is the real format in iOS ? 
what are steps to connect with https ?

I see a lot of forums with the method :

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

But i don t understand what send in Nsurlauthenticationchallenge etc ...

I really need help please .

Comment: Please anybody can help me ? I have to send a certificate to the server ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get detail info to beget connected with https using Apple's [**Making HTTP and HTTPS Requests**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what is the format used by ios ?